# Payment Received/Outstanding Interface

Tags: web-app, status, payment

We're working on an internal tool to show and edit the status of payments received.  To give you an idea:

[image]

**Is there a better way to represent this?**

Each row is associated with an item and there could be many items.  We want to be able to update and show the current amount collected without leaving the screen.  Thinking that we'll use the placeholder for the Collected input text field for the actual amount (with some magic to support incompatible browsers).

Sorry for the poor image.  It's going through edits.

Comment: It looks like you accept multiple payments if there is a $__Remaining.  If that's the case then what does `Collection Date` mean?  The last time anything was paid or will you have multiple rows showing each payment portion?

Comment: It's meant for entry of the most recent payment, rather than history.  Thinking that Edit Details can show the history.

Comment: At a minimum I would expect to see `Customer A` paid `$0` and still owes `$1,410`.  Is the name of the person who owes the money kept private?

Comment: The customer is just truncated from the example (I'm showing an excerpt), but you can think of it appearing on the left.

Comment: And yes, it would be possible for a customer to make partial payments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple things I would try...

### 1. In-line editing with some safeguards

Making changes to an item directly in the list is nice since it provides context, however, consider making the list read-only until the user specifically clicks an "Edit" button.  This will help highlight that the user is making the desired change to the right row and allow them a way to cancel all their changes if needed.

### 2. Quick filter buttons

It would be nice if I could see just the items that are **Past Due** or **Partially Paid** in a single click.

[image]

*note: the columns shown above can be anything and are not part of the answer*

Since this is an internal tool, the good news is that you have direct access to your users and may even be able to observe how they use it in their own environment.

Good luck!